# Raspberry pi permanently change if metric

Tags: raspbian

I have a raspberry pi running raspbian, with eth0 connected to a local network and wlan0 connected to my router. For this to work, I need to set the metric for wlan0 to a lower value than eth0.
I have done this in dhcpcd.conf, and confirmed that it works by restarting the dhcpc service.

But after a reboot, the metrics are restored to their default values. Restarting the dhcpc service will update the metrics correctly and then it works until the next reboot.

How can I go about making this change permanent? Should I perhaps configure the interfaces somewhere else?

I have added the following two lines to /etc/dhcpcd.conf:

```
interface eth0
metric 800
```

Comment: Downvoting my question without stating a reason makes it very difficult to improve it. Perhaps the reason is that you did not understand it, in which case it is not the question that is wrong.

Comment: The reason was that ServerFault is for questions about managing computer systems in a business environment. So your question was off topic there.

Comment: Why do you need to change metric? Is the IP ranges equal?

Comment: Reason for changing is that both etthernet and wifi are connected, with ethernet being a local network only. Internet is available through wifi. Default metric puts ethernet before wifi.

Comment: @NikitaKipriyanov thank you for explaining the reason. I will make sure to use the correct forum the next time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was solved by switching from *dhcpc* to *Network Manager*.
The command line interface, nmcli, offers many advanced settings that are difficult to do elsewhere.